# Animate smoothly and continuously the scale of an object show flickering

Tags: android, animation

I have a method (updateValue) that is called at fixed rate (example: 300ms). I need change the scale of a view (between 0.1 - 1.0), this means I need start animations continuously

I'm doing of the following way

```
public static void updateScale(final View view, Double newValue) {
    if (dB == null) {
        dB = MAX_DB;
    }

    float to = (float) (newValue / MAX_VALUE);
    long time = 500;


    if (to > 1f) {
        to = 1f;
    }

    Animation anim = (Animation) view.getTag(R.string.anim_tag);
    Object animScale = view.getTag(R.string.anim_scale);

    final float from = animScale == null ? 1f : (float)animScale;


    float diff = Math.abs(from - to);

    if (diff < 0.00001) {
        Log.d(BuildConfig.TAG, "Skip no animation");
        return;
    }

    if (anim == null || anim.hasEnded()) {
        anim = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 1f, from, to);
        anim.setDuration(time);
        anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                view.setScaleY(from);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        view.setTag(R.string.anim_tag, anim);
        view.setTag(R.string.anim_scale, to);
        view.startAnimation(anim);
    } else {
        view.setTag(R.string.anim_scale, to);
    }
}
```

The animation appears be smooth, but there's like a flickering. I've tried different ways, also why for some reason I need set the scale when the animation ends or start ii order to keep the change on the view